# spring boot websocket with postman always return 403

Tags: spring, postman, spring-websocket

I'm trying to make my stomp chat app work.

```
override fun configureMessageBroker(config: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/user")
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user")
}


override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
    registry
        .addEndpoint("/ws")
        .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
        .withSockJS()
}
```

This is my code to enable stomp messaging
When i access localhost:8080/ws via chrome I get "Welcome to SockJS"
But when I do this via postman then I get 403. I get 403 no matter what endpoint I'm trying to connect to, even with localhost:8080/qwsadasdw (this one doesn't exists obviously). Is it possible to make it work via postman?